# Volume form of a pseudo-Riemannian manifold, but restricted to the light cone

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, volume

On a Riemannian manifold one can define the volume over the totality of the manifold $M$

$$
V=\int_M F(x,y,z,t)\sqrt{|g|}\mathrm dx\wedge\mathrm dy\wedge\mathrm{d}z\wedge \mathrm dt.
$$

But on a pseudo-Riemannian manifold --- I have a 4-manifold with Lorentz signature in mind ---, can I define define a volume within the 'light cone' of an observer at point $p_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0,t_0)$.

It seems like if I limit the scope of my integral to the volume delimited by the light cone (I sum over the points $p_i$ where $d(p_0,p_i)>0$), and if I limit my change of coordinates to other observers within the light cone of $p_0$, then I should get most if not all of the properties of a volume --- such that it is always positive, etc. Is it a 'volume' in the traditional geometric sense?

Comment: even on any pseudo-Riemannian, oriented manifold, $(M,g)$ you can always define a volume form $\mu_g$ associated to $g$, which in terms of a positively oriented coordinate system $(x^1,\dots, x^n)$ is given by $\mu_g=\sqrt{|\det g_{(x), ij}|}dx^1\wedge\cdots \wedge dx^n$. If $M$ is not orientable then you don't have a volume form, but you can still define a measure (in the sense of measure theory) $\lambda_g$, which is a positive, complete, $\sigma$-finite and defined on the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra of $M$. So yes, this is a volume in the geometric sense.

Comment: also, light cones belong to the tangent space of the manifold, they are not part of the manifold itself (unless you're dealing with $M=\Bbb{R}^4$, in which case you can make all sorts of identifications so that everything is already trivial).